# Как запретить повторную анимацию при выполнении текущей?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Что только ни делал: и `stop();` применял - не помогает). Вот [пример](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggle/).

P.S. Очень нужно, пишу меню и там свертка есть, а без toggle не обойтись.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
function runEffect() {
  if($( "#effect" ).is(":animated")) return;
...
};
```

Comment: спс испробую, а вы тестировали?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xdfsn/ Вроде работает.

Comment: а по-моему нет

Comment: Ну работает или нет, проверять вам конечно, возможно обработчик у вас срабатывает до начала анимации, поэтому условие ложно.

Короче говоря, идея в том, чтобы прерывать вызов обработчика если идет анимация. Ставьте флаг в начале функции, в колбэк-функции toggle снимайте его.

Answer (score 0):

пробуйте stop(true);
Должно работать. Возможно stop не для того объекта вызываете

[stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: вот не надо мне тут ляля я все свойства stop использовал даже такие как stop(true,true) или stop(false,true)